# How to render 3 most recent Mongo items using Jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I'm building an app with node, mongo, and jade, that allows me to add items to a database, and then have those items rendered on a page using jade. This is a content site, so I only want the three most recent database items to be rendered on the page. When I use a for loop in jade, it runs through the entire database and creates a new DOM element for each item in the db. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
for item in docs
            div(class='item')
                div(class='overlayHover')
                div(class='protectLink')
                    a(class='readMore' href='#') READ MORE
                    div(class='overlayText')
                        h3 #{item.description}
                img(class='triImage' src='http://cdn.modernfarmer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ChiangMai10.jpg')
            div(class='item')
                div(class='overlayHover')
                div(class='protectLink')
                    a(class='readMore' href='#') READ MORE
                    div(class='overlayText')
                        h3 #{item.description}
                img(class='triImage' src='http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/6e/f1/82/6ef182a1085c987bf8143d9b2d4ea42b.jpg')
            div(class='item')
                div(class='overlayHover')
                div(class='protectLink')
                    a(class='readMore' href='#') READ MORE
                    div(class='overlayText')
                        h3 #{item.description}
                img(class='triImage' src='http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0257/8507/products/warren-keelan-surf-photo13sq_medium.jpg?v=1395110040')
```

I don't think the for loop is what I'm looking for. I would like for these three elements to be fixed, the only thing that changes is their item.description.

Is there a specific jade method I should be looking at in order to pull only the three most recent items from my mongo database?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Jade is not pulling anything from the MongoDB. It is merely displaying what you are passing to it. If you want to limit and sort your data either change your MongoDB query or preprocess the document array before passing them to Jade.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. Is it possible to send multiple objects to jade? For example res.render('index' , {docs:docs, items:items})?

Comment: @user3294779 Yes, that would work just fine. More generally, I think you will have more convenient maintenance if you select only the three elements you want, or truncate the array (e.g. using slice) to three elements, and then use a for loop inside your Jade. It will just be much cleaner. Also it is mildly ironic to have the redundancy in such a terse template language. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like [Amberlamps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191261/amberlamps) mentioned it would be better to only pass the 3 recent objects to your template, but your `for each` loop will suddenly post 9 times then, it should look more like:

```
for item in docs
  div(class='item')
    div(class='overlayHover')
    div(class='protectLink')
      a(class='readMore' href='#') READ MORE
      div(class='overlayText')
        h3 #{item.description}
  img(class='triImage' src='http://cdn.modernfarmer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ChiangMai10.jpg')
```

But if you still want to handle your problem in Jade, here a quick demo, with an example that would work right now for you:

```
- for(var i = docs.length-1; i >= docs.length-3; i--)
  div(class='item')
    div(class='overlayHover')
    div(class='protectLink')
      a(class='readMore' href='#') READ MORE
      div(class='overlayText')
        h3 #{docs[i].description}
    img(class='triImage' src='http://cdn.modernfarmer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ChiangMai10.jpg')
```

I just added a new `for` loop. This will do nothing else as start with the last item in your passed element and post your data backwards.

Here my example data:

```
{
  docs: [
    {description: '1 Demo'},
    {description: '2 Demo'},
    {description: '3 Demo'},
    {description: '4 Demo'},
    {description: '5 Demo'}
  ]
}
```

And here the final result:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="overlayHover"></div>
  <div class="protectLink"><a href="#" class="readMore">READ MORE</a>
    <div class="overlayText">
      <h3>5 Demo</h3>
    </div>
  </div><img src="http://cdn.modernfarmer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ChiangMai10.jpg" class="triImage"/>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="overlayHover"></div>
  <div class="protectLink"><a href="#" class="readMore">READ MORE</a>
    <div class="overlayText">
      <h3>4 Demo</h3>
    </div>
  </div><img src="http://cdn.modernfarmer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ChiangMai10.jpg" class="triImage"/>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="overlayHover"></div>
  <div class="protectLink"><a href="#" class="readMore">READ MORE</a>
    <div class="overlayText">
      <h3>3 Demo</h3>
    </div>
  </div><img src="http://cdn.modernfarmer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ChiangMai10.jpg" class="triImage"/>
</div>
```